# setOnItemClickListener on ListView after AsyncTask finished

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-listview, android-asynctask, onitemclicklistener

I've setup a `ListView` and a `SimpleAdapter` that get data through a function which runs in a `AsyncTask` but the problem is that I now want to set an `setOnItemClickListener`on this `ListView`.

The problem is that I'm trying to attach a `setOnItemClickListener` but this is getting attached before my `AsyncTask` is finished in the `onLoad`, which means there is no bind.

So my question is how can I let the `Async` execute and finish to fill up my `ListView` and bind the `setOnItemClickListener` **after** my `Async` task is finished?

**Note:** I've updated my answer with the full code of the class and the view, since this was asked by an user and will give more insight to others. For the full code please scroll down to the **Update** part!

The code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_overview);
    //Context inladen
    context = ContactOverview.this;

        listViewContacts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewContacts);

    //new GetAllContactsAsync().execute();
    asny.execute();
            Log.i("finished?","finished?");
            Log.i("listLength", "" + listViewContacts.getCount());
            listViewContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(ContactOverview.this, "ee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("test","test");
                }

            }); 
}
```

the `listViewContacts.setOnItemClickListener` should be attached **after** the `Async` task is finished. So how should I do this? If my `listViewContacts.setOnItemClickListener`is triggered before my `Async` task is done the bind will not be made..

**UPDATE: FULL CODE**

**ListView (contact_overview.xml)**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:background="#1e78bc">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewContacts"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:shadowColor="#f9f9f9"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Row for listview (row.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/customerName"
android:paddingLeft="3dp"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/customerPhone"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
android:paddingRight="3dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_below="@id/customerName"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/telefoon"
android:autoLink="phone"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/customerGsm"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
android:paddingRight="3dp"
android:layout_below="@id/customerName"
android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/customerPhone"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/telefoon"
android:autoLink="phone"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/customerEmail"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
android:layout_below="@id/customerPhone"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:autoLink="email"/>

<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/customerZip"
android:paddingLeft="3dp"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/user"
android:layout_below="@id/customerEmail"/>

<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/customerCity"
android:paddingLeft="3dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/customerZip"
android:layout_below="@+id/customerEmail"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/customerStreet"
android:paddingRight="3dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/customerCity"
android:layout_below="@+id/customerEmail"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Class for filling the ListView (ContactOverview.java)**

```
public class ContactOverview extends ActionBarActivity  {
public int uid = 0;
final String url = "dev.myurl.com";
final int port = 8072;
final String dbName = "dbname";
final String username = "dbPass";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Context context;
ArrayList<Object> customerArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> companyArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
List companyList = null;
List customerList = null;
ListView listViewContacts;
int finished = 0;
GetAllContactsAsync asny = new GetAllContactsAsync();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contact_overview);
    //Context inladen
    context = ContactOverview.this;
    //new GetAllContactsAsync().execute();
    listViewContacts =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewContacts);
    asny.execute();
    listViewContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(ContactOverview.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
}

private class GetAllContactsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> 
{
    //Before running code in separate thread  
    @Override  
    protected void onPreExecute()  
    {  
        //Create a new progress dialog  
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ContactOverview.this);  
        //Set the progress dialog to display a horizontal progress bar  
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);  
        //Set the dialog title to 'Loading...'  
        progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.loading);  
        //Set the dialog message to 'Loading application View, please wait...'  
        progressDialog.setMessage(ContactOverview.this.getString(R.string.loadingMessage));  
        //This dialog can't be canceled by pressing the back key  
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);  
        //This dialog isn't indeterminate  
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);  
        //The maximum number of items is 100  
        progressDialog.setMax(100);  
        //Set the current progress to zero  
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        //Display the progress dialog  
        progressDialog.show();  
    }  

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            //Get the current thread's token  
            synchronized (this)  
            {  
                //counter progress dialog  
                int counter = 0;  
                //Wait 100 milliseconds  
                this.wait(200);
                try 
                {
                    //get uid
                    uid = Connect(url, port, dbName, username, "myPass");
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e1) 
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, context.getString(R.string.authenticateError), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Models en connectie maken voor xml-rpc
                XmlRpcClient models = null;
                try 
                {
                    models = new XmlRpcClient() {{
                        /*was: 
                        setConfig(new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl() {{
                        setServerURL(new URL(String.format("http://%s:%s/xmlrpc/2/object", "dev.myurl.com", port)));
                        }});
                        }};
                        */
                    setConfig(new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl() {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    {
                    setServerURL(new URL(String.format("http://%s:%s/xmlrpc/2/object", "dev.myurl.com", port)));
                    }});
                    }};
                } 
                catch (MalformedURLException e1) 
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Loading to 20%
                counter += 20;
                publishProgress(counter);
                try
                {
                    /*final Array list = (Array)models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList(
                    dbName, uid, "myPass",
                    "res.partner", "search",
                    Arrays.asList(new HashMap() {{
                        Arrays.asList("is_company", "=", "true");
                        Arrays.asList("customer", "=", "true");
                        }})
                            ));
                    Log.i("Array", "" + list);*/


                    customerList = (List)Arrays.asList((Object[])models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList(
                    dbName, uid, "myPass",
                    "res.partner", "search_read",
                    Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(
                        Arrays.asList("customer", "=", true))),
                    new HashMap() {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    {
                        put("fields", Arrays.asList("name", "phone", "mobile","email","website", "street", "city", "zip"));
                        put("limit", 0);
                    }}
                    )));

                    Log.i("customerList",""+customerList);

                    //30% further in progressdialog
                    counter += 30;
                    publishProgress(counter);

                    companyList = (List)Arrays.asList((Object[])models.execute("execute_kw", Arrays.asList(
                    dbName, uid, "myPass",
                    "res.partner", "search_read",
                    Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(
                        Arrays.asList("is_company", "=", true))),
                    new HashMap() {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    {
                        put("fields", Arrays.asList("name", "phone", "mobile","email","website", "street", "city", "zip"));
                        put("limit", 0);
                    }}
                    )));

                    //Another 30% further (= 80%)
                    counter += 30;
                    publishProgress(counter);
                    //customerArray = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(customerObject));
                    //companyArray = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(companyObject));
                    //Log.i("Customers", "object: " + customerObject);

                    //parsing, now at @90%.
                    counter += 20;
                    publishProgress(counter);
                    //100% after data is parsed in parseDataInLijsten()
                    counter += 10;
                    publishProgress(counter);
                } 
                catch (XmlRpcException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                publishProgress(counter);
            }  
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  


 //Update the progress  
    @Override  
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)  
    {  
        //set the current progress of the progress dialog  
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);  
    }  

    //Parse data from here on and then show it. (parseDataInLijsten does this)  
    @Override  
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
    {  
        //close the progress dialog  
        progressDialog.dismiss();  
        //initialize the View    
        //show ListView on screen. 
        parseDataInLijsten();
           Log.i("listViewContacts987", "" + listViewContacts.getCount());
    }  
}

//Finally parse the data and show it in the ListView.
private void parseDataInLijsten()
{

    //Vars
    HashMap testMap = null;
    String phone = null;
    String gsm = null;
    String id = null;
    String email = null;
    String name = null;
    String street = null;
    String city = null;
    String website = null;
    String zip = null;
    List<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    //ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

    listViewContacts = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewContacts);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //Loopen over every record in the list. This is per company.
    for(int teller = 0; teller < companyList.size(); teller++)
    {
        //HashMap contains one set 
        testMap = (HashMap) companyList.get(teller);
        int teller2 = 0;
        //every value is an item in the list of a record
        for (Object value : testMap.values()) {
            teller2++;
            if(teller2 == 1)
            {
                street = value.toString();
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("street", street);
            }
            if(teller2 == 2)
            {
                id = value.toString();
                map.put("id",id);
            }
            if(teller2 == 3)
            {
                gsm = value.toString();
                if(gsm == "false")
                {
                    gsm = "-";
                }
                map.put("gsm", gsm);
            }
            if(teller2 == 4)
            {
                website = value.toString();
                if(website == "false")
                {
                    website = "-";
                }
                map.put("website", website);
            }
            if(teller2 == 5)
            {
                city = value.toString();
                if(city == "false")
                {
                    city = "";
                }
                map.put("city", city + " - ");
            }
            if(teller2 == 6)
            {
                email = value.toString();
                if(email == "false")
                {
                    email = "";
                }
                map.put("email", email);
            }
            if(teller2 == 7)
            {
                phone = value.toString();
                if(phone == "false")
                {
                    phone = "-";
                }
                map.put("phone", phone);
            }
            if(teller2 == 8)
            {
                name = value.toString();
                map.put("name", name);
            }
            if(teller2 == 9)
            {
                zip = value.toString();
                map.put("zip", zip + " ");
                if(zip == "false")
                {
                    zip = "";
                }
                mylist2.add(map);
            }
        }

    }


    SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist2, R.layout.row,
                new String[] {"name","phone", "gsm", "email", "zip", "city", "street"}, new int[] {R.id.customerName, R.id.customerPhone, R.id.customerGsm,
            R.id.customerEmail,
            R.id.customerZip, R.id.customerCity, R.id.customerStreet});
    listViewContacts.setAdapter(mSchedule);
}
}
```

Thanks
Yenthe

Comment: put that setOnItemClickListener of yours in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask

Comment: As long as you use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged in asynctask to refresh listview, this should work fine. Why do you want to attach listener after asynctask's completion? Any reason?

Comment: SarthakMittal that doesn't work either, nothing gets triggered if I click on an item in the listview then.
@MagicalPhoenixϡ I want to attach the listener after the asynctask because I fill the listviews from my Async task (due to it being quite a lot of data and showing a custom loading screen).
I'll update the code a little bit more to add the onPostExecute too.

Comment: if onPostExecute is not called, it means that your async is still runing : your code in doInBackground are still running

Comment: @HugoG the onPostExecute gets called and finishes too. I can put Log.i in it and it prints and if I create a second function that waits xxx seconds for my Async task to finish I'll see that there are 28 items in my ListView, which is also correct. So sadly that is not the problem I think..

Comment: Plz update your   question with the full Async Class and the other code for the ListView/CustomAdapter if any

Comment: @HugoG I've added the whole code of the class, ListView and row XML. I hope this helps you out any further..

Comment: Did you ever solve this @Yenthe? Having the same problem for about 2 weeks.

Comment: @COYG I never found a solution for this and went with another approach. Sorry.

Comment: @Yenthe Looks like i'll have to change approach too. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Yenthe Check out my last question in my history, a good man found a fix for me if your still curious as to know.

Answer (score 0):

Put this attribute into each TextView

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```